# StreamAnalyticsJob Blob Output produces as many files as the number of partitions of input EventHub?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I have an EventHub(containing json formatted entity as events) which is input to my Stream Analytics Job. I have created 4 partitions on my EH but do not have any partition key so the data is distributed in RoundRobin theoretically.

My StreamAnlytics query is as simple as SELECT * FROM `EventHub` OUTPUT TO `BLOB`. The blob output has a configuration of data aggregation every 5mins and the file format is `<date><HH>`.

I see 4 files per hour on my blob storage, is this expected? Does SA internally reads each partition separately at the same time?

Sorry if it might sound naïve, I am new to this and curious to know how SA works internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is expected.

A Stream Analytics job can consume and write different partitions in parallel, which increases throughput.

For more details, please refer to [Partitions in inputs and outputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-parallelization#partitions-in-inputs-and-outputs).

Comment: Thank you @Ivan Yang.

Comment: Is this behaviour always guaranteed? The number of output files being equal to the number of partitions in the EventHub if we do not specify any PartitionKey/ID?